# ffmpeg: using the returned data in php

Tags: php, ssh, ffmpeg, backticks

I have started using `ffmpeg` and I am very new to it, so please bear with me.

I have installed `ffmpeg` on my server and it works great; I can run certain commands and get output data when logged in via ssh

For example I can run

```
ffmpeg -i Sleep\ Away.mp3
```

Which returns the following:

```
ffmpeg version 0.8.5, Copyright (c) 2000-2011 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Aug 20 2012 09:28:43 with clang 3.1 (tags/Apple/clang-318.0.61)
  configuration: --enable-nonfree --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-postproc --enable-swscale --enable-avfilter --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libvorbis --enable-libtheora --enable-libfaac --enable-libxvid --enable-libx264 --enable-libvpx --enable-hardcoded-tables --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --disable-indevs --cc=clang
  libavutil    51.  9. 1 / 51.  9. 1
  libavcodec   53.  7. 0 / 53.  7. 0
  libavformat  53.  4. 0 / 53.  4. 0
  libavdevice  53.  1. 1 / 53.  1. 1
  libavfilter   2. 23. 0 /  2. 23. 0
  libswscale    2.  0. 0 /  2.  0. 0
  libpostproc  51.  2. 0 / 51.  2. 0
[mp3 @ 0x7f9694011a00] Header missing
    Last message repeated 13 times
[mp3 @ 0x7f9694007c00] max_analyze_duration 5000000 reached at 5007020
[mp3 @ 0x7f9694007c00] Estimating duration from bitrate, this may be inaccurate
Input #0, mp3, from 'Sleep Away.mp3':
  Metadata:
    track           : 3
    album           : Bob Acri
    artist          : Bob Acri
    title           : Sleep Away
    genre           : Jazz
    album_artist    : Bob Acri
    composer        : Robert R. Acri
    date            : 2004
  Duration: 00:03:21.77, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 192 kb/s
    Stream #0.0: Audio: mp3, 44100 Hz, stereo, s16, 192 kb/s
At least one output file must be specified
```

The question I am asking is, how can I use the output data above? I am developiong a music website; say I want to loop through all the MP3 files and save the info about them into a database, so that the above would result in:

```
Sleep Away.mp3    mp3    3:21    Jazz    2004     Bob Acri ...
```

obviously in a table

I have tried to use the php *backtick* operator with no success so far. I just thought I would put a question up here to get some advice from people that have done something similar.

Thanks

**Update**: I have tried the following

```
<?php $output = `ffmpeg -i Sleep\ Away.mp3`; echo "<pre>$output</pre>"; ?>
<?php $output = shell_exec('ffmpeg -i Sleep\ Away.mp3'); echo "<pre>$output</pre>"; ?>
```

both don't appear to return anything.

Comment: what is the problem when you try with the backtick operator? Could you provide the code you use, and the resulting output?

Comment: hi thanks for the reply i have tried shell_exec with the following <?php $output = shell_exec('ffmpeg -i Sleep\ Away.mp3'); echo "<pre>$output</pre>"; but this doesn't return anything to me i have installed ffmpeg on my mac osx lion where am i going wrong

Comment: please update the question instead of writing the same in two comments; it's me twice you're writing to anyway ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ffmpeg` sends that information on standard **error**, and not to standard *output* which is what `shell_exec()` captures.

You need to add: `2>&1` at the end of your command:

```
$out = shell_exec('/path/to/ffmpeg -i Sleep\ Away.mp3 2>&1');
```

Comment: good point, would have been my next suggestion. I should have tried a more analytical approach instead of an exclusion procedure ;)

Comment: you sir are a legend thanks this worked for me <?php
$output = shell_exec('/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg -i Sleep\ Away.mp3 2>&1');
echo "<pre>$output</pre>"; awesome so i take it i just run a regex to grab the appropriate info ;)

Comment: Thanks, but take heed of Nyarlatothep's answer (I'm upvoting it) -- in the general case, thats' much more helpful to track shell_exec problems.

Answer (score 1):

So you want to execute a shell command (ffmpeg in your case) from php, and capture its output, right?

Backtick Operator or the [shell_exec](http://php.net/manual/de/function.shell-exec.php) function are a good start for that.

Note that these only work when safe mode is disabled and when shell_exec function is not disabled (via disable_functions setting). If your scripts are running on a shared hoster, you might not have access to these configurations, but you should at least be able to check them via phpinfo().

How you specify the path to any file you are referencing in the command is also crucial - your php script might not run with the working folder you expect it to run; so it might be best to reference to all files via absolute path.

Comment: hi thanks for the reply i have tried shell_exec with the following <?php
$output = shell_exec('ffmpeg -i Sleep\ Away.mp3');
echo "<pre>$output</pre>"; but this doesn't return anything to me i have installed ffmpeg on my mac osx lion where am i going wrong

Comment: what about the configuration options I mentioned? what are they set to? what about file paths (relative vs. absolute, see updated answer)

Comment: just checked my php.ini file and safe mode is set to off allow_call_time_pass_reference = On

; Safe Mode
;
safe_mode = Off

Comment: are you running the php from the command line or via the browser? have you tried referencing the "Sleep\ Away.mp3" with full absolute path?

Answer (score 1):

**Use [FFprobe](http://ffmpeg.org/ffprobe.html) instead:**

```
ffprobe -loglevel error -show_format -show_streams input.mp3
```

FFmpeg is for manipulating video, FFprobe is the accompanying tool for getting video information.  It outputs data in a variety of easily parsed formats instead of requiring parsing the diagnostic messages that FFmpeg incidentally spits out when importing a video.